# writing a network sync in bash functions (rsync?)

Tags: shell-script

So I am new to bash programming, and I am trying to write a program that automatically syncs files between my pc and laptop. Both use ubuntu 19. I have a folder called ~/share on both computers, and I was wondering what methods would be the best to use to sync these folders. I heard rsync might work, I was just looking for imput.

Comment: Take a look at **unison** (https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/); it was built for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try unison 
Or
rsync -u -aSH

The -u is important to not overwrite files that are newer on the other side.

The other way I really like as a programmer, is to use a git repo. This will keep the full change history and do better merges of offline changes and allow for multiple backup locations.

Comment: Using git is good idea, but not for this use-case. There is no automatically syncing and the permanent history will take a lot of space if he has large files.